# sampling from an unknown bivariate distribution

Tags: sampling, monte-carlo, copula

I want to generate samples from a bivariate distribution whose joint PDF doesn't resemble any known distribution.

I have two events A and B where B depends on A.

I have empirical observations of the marginals and the joint distributions.

I know the sample correlation matrix and the covariance matrix.

Say A looks roughly Poisson and B looks roughly bimodal (some Beta distribution).

What's the best approach?

1) Generate random samples from a Poisson and a Beta then use a copula to transform these so that original sample covariance is maintained

2) Use MCMC to find the MLE parameters of a the Beta given the values of the observed values of the Poisson, then randomly sample from the Poisson and find the maximum likely value of the Beta given its optimal parameters.

Comment: Both A and B are vectors of values generated from random variables

Comment: You cannot generate from an undefined distribution.

Comment: I see. Then say A is generated from the Burr distribution and B from the DGamma distribution.

Comment: These are the marginal distributions. The joint need be defined as well, for instance via a copula as in option (1). Option (2) is more problematic as it mixes simulation and estimation.

Comment: So using a copula would produce a simulation that maintained the joint distribution of the original two conditional random variables?

Comment: I would rather say that using a specific copula determines a specific correlation structure between the two random variables, while preserving their marginal distributions.